# Why can logical constness only be added to a std::span of const pointers?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-span

Consider this code that attempts to create various `std::span` objects for a vector of raw pointers.

```
#include <vector>
#include <span>

int main()
{
    struct S {};
    std::vector<S*> v;
    std::span<S*> span1{v};
    std::span<S* const> span2{v};
    std::span<const S* const> span3{v};
    std::span<const S*> span4{v};
    return 0;
}
```

`span3` compiles fine, but `span4` fails with the following error:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:58:32: error: no matching function for call to 'std::span<const main()::S*>::span(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
   58 |     std::span<const S*> span4{v};
      |                                ^
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/ranges:45,
                 from <source>:5:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/span:231:9: note: candidate: 'template<class _OType, long unsigned int _OExtent>  requires (_Extent == std::dynamic_extent || _OExtent == std::dynamic_extent || _Extent == _OExtent) && (std::__is_array_convertible<_Type, _Tp>::value) constexpr std::span<_Type, _Extent>::span(const std::span<_OType, _OExtent>&) [with long unsigned int _OExtent = _OType; _Type = const main()::S*; long unsigned int _Extent = 18446744073709551615]'
```

I would either expected `span3` and `span4` both to fail or both to succeed.  Can someone explain why logical constness can be added to to a `std::span` of raw pointers iff the underlying pointer is `const` (i.e. bitwise).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `std::span<const S*>` allows you to assign a `const S*` to an element.
2. `std::vector<S*>` allows you to read an element of type `S*`.
3. If `std::span<const S*>` were allowed to take a `std::vector<S*>`, then it would be possible to sneakily convert a `const S*` to a `S*`, by assigning the `const S*` to an element of the span and then reading the same element through the vector.

That is to say, if `std::span<const S*> span4{v};` were allowed, then the following program would be valid:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <span>

int main()
{
    struct S { int value; };
    std::vector<S*> v = {nullptr};
    std::span<const S*> span4{v}; // Note: not allowed in reality

    const S s{.value = 0};

    span4[0] = &s;
    S* p = v[0];
    assert(p == &s);
    p->value = 42; // Oops, modifies the value of a const object!
}
```

So in order to prevent this scenario and provide const-correctness, `std::span<const S*>` must not be constructible from a `std::vector<S*>`.

On the other hand, `std::span<const S* const>` does not allow you to assign to its elements, so it's safe for it to take a `std::vector<S*>`.

(Yes, it's the same reason that you can convert a `S**` to `const S* const *`, but you cannot convert it to `const S**`.)